# How allow to fit read_only field for new record in TabularInline class in Django

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to have a field readonly when record already saved but if admin adds a new record field must to be editable.

How I can achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ModelAdmin's [get_readonly_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_readonly_fields) method for this purpose. When the object is created, the obj is set to None. By overriding the method, you can change the read_only fields if obj is present or not.

```
def get_readonly_fields(self, obj):
    if obj:
       return ['field_1', 'field_2']
    else:  # When object is created
       return [] # no editable field
```

References:

- https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-admin-cookbook/en/latest/uneditable_existing.html
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_readonly_fields